# How can I restart a service on Nixos?

Tags: nix, nixos

I've enabled the emacs daemon in my 'nix' config via:

`services.emacs.enable = true;`

However I'd now like to restart the daemon, due to changing my emacs config.

How can I restart it?

`systemctl list-unit-files | grep emacs` does not return any results  (it would also be useful to know why).

```
pstree -s emacs
-+= 00001 root systemd 
 \-+= 01301 chris /nix/store/3hmpbbcv1db42m9g34c9g4q6qinw50x4-systemd-237/lib/systemd/systemd --user 
   \-+= 01351 chris /nix/store/zkss82a853cv9d8w9iq25cp26q3jh4fp-emacs-25.3/bin/.emacs-wrapped --daemon 
     \--= 01414 chris /run/current-system/sw/bin/ispell -a -m -B
```

Comment: The [module](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/editors/emacs.nix#L84) looks quite boring. Did you `nixos-rebuild switch`?

Comment: Yup that was done many times (and numerous reboots).

Comment: It seems that something else is wrong. The description of [services.emacs.install](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.emacs.install) suggests that you have to be explicit about having a 'user' service: `--user`. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
systemctl --user restart emacs
```