# Emacs daemon slowing down shutdown

Tags: emacs, nixos

Recently, I set `services.emacs.enable = true;` on my `configuration.nix`. I've noticed that, during shutdown, an annoying timeout shows up. Here's what I see:

```
[  OK  ] Stopped X11 Server.
[  OK  ] Stopped Session 2 of user <myUsername>.
         Stopping Login Service.
         Stopping User Manager for UID 1001.
[  OK  ] Stopped Login Service.
[ ***  ] A stop job is running for User Manager for UID 1001 (1min 32s / 2min 3s)
```

My understanding is that a second systemd instance is created to manage these services. Looking at `top` I can see it fathering both a `pulseaudio` and an `.emacs-26.3-wra` process. The nix expressions for the Emacs service does have an `execStop` attribute, but I suspect some `recentf` interference or some other function in Emacs itself prompting and preventing instant death.

Before enabling the Emacs service, I never had this issue, and simply by deactivating it, the issue dissapears. I suppose one way of brute-forcing my way out of the problem would be to place a `killall -9 .emacs-26.3-wra` somewhere in the options, but I'm not sure where (already tried at `services.xserver.displayManager.sddm.stopScript`, to no avail.

So my question is, short of forking `nixpkgs` to change the stop function, or of doing the same on Emacs, is there a way of ensuring instant termination of the Emacs process? I already looked and have `confirm-kill-emacs` set to nil. This is my current `configuration.nix`:
[configuration.nix](https://gist.github.com/LuisChDev/301b20bb5d34ce2cb892bee22196ee9f). I'm not a power user by any means. So your help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Is systemd (or any other service manager) actually a factor here?  If you try to stop the Emacs server *manually* (using the same method that the service manager is using -- you'll need to find out what that is), does it work?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/editors/emacs.nix#L91) the config you're using?  If so, that's presumably the command to try.

Comment: Or potentially use the [systemctl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53366356/324105) command to stop the service (this is the Q&A from which I found the link to that config file).

Comment: @phils Can you turn that last comment into an answer, so I can mark it as right? :-) It fixed the problem, specifically, `systemctl --user stop emacs` does stop the emacs process imperatively, yet it comes back to life after a reboot. I changed the kill command on my question with this one, and now shutdown works as intended

Comment: I may have spoken too fast, it only worked the first time :-(. I've been experimenting and noticed the same delay when using the systemctl command manually. What I know now is, it lags _only_ if there is no client open. If I try to stop the service without a client running, it lags, then if i open the client i get immediately prompted with `Buffer recentf modified, kill anyway? (y or n)`. I have no idea why this is, but I'm going to try with this solution (opening a client just before shutdown), just in case.

Comment: Ok, finally, I think that's it. Tried to deactivate recentf-mode. No luck either, something else on my config must be reactivating it, however, simply keeping an emacs client open right before shutdown seems to fix the issue. (Weirdly enough, if it's open, it won't ask for confirmation before saving the recentf file). I tried auto opening a client, did not work, but the fact that the problem has a solution now means I get to sleep tonight ;-D

Comment: Try `M-x debug-on-entry` for `recentf-mode` to learn what is calling that function.  Refer to `C-h i g (elisp)Debugger Commands` for exiting the debugger, and you can `M-x cancel-debug-on-entry` once you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone who stumbles upon this question, I found [this issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12873) which describes the same situation. Turns out this is really a problem with Spacemacs, specifically, the `kill-emacs-hook` and some cleanup code. After trying with many different approaches, the only one that worked for me was the one in the thread, adding `persp-mode` to `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages`.